# Firestore .get() resulting in deadline exceeded

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm running the following code from [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data):

```
docs = db.collection(u'cities').get()

for doc in docs:
    print(doc.id)
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 74, in <module>
    main()
  File "...", line 53, in main
    for doc in docs:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1beta1/query.py", line 588, in get
    for index, response_pb in enumerate(response_iterator):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 347, in next
    return self._next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 338, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, Deadline Exceeded)>
```

Is there some issue with the python lib? I'm not even running any queries or anything, so I'm surprised that a straightforward index operation would time out. I also have no idea how to debug this further since the documentation doesn't mention anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is due to running on Windows Subsystem for Linux. Apparently, the performance of Firestore is sufficiently slow on WSL (I think due to filesystem operations) that the default timeout is too short.